# Mocking Laravel Model::increment() with Mockery

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, codeception, mockery

I have a line of code in a Laravel 5 event handler which looks like this:

```
$this->event->batch->increment('attempted_jobs');
```

`$this->event` is the event which calls the handler and `$this->event->batch` contains my `Batch` model. All this does in increment the `attempted_jobs` column within my database, so it's fairly basic stuff.

I would like to be able to test this event handler, I'm using Codeception and Mockery. My mock for `$this->event->batch` looks like this:

```
$batch = m::mock('MyVendor\MyApp\Batch');
$batch->shouldReceive('increment')->once()->with('attempted_jobs');
```

This however causes issues - `increment()` is a protected method of `Model` and therefore cannot be mocked. Here's the exact error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: increment() cannot be mocked as it a protected method and mocking protected methods is not allowed for this mock
```

It appears to be implemented using the `__call()` PHP magic method, so how to I mock this? I've attempted creating a `__call()` mock, but this churns out tonnes of errors related to the `increment()` method not being implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because, as stated, `increment()` is a protected method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model()`. The way to get around this is to mock the `__call()` method directly, like so:

```
$batch = m::mock('MyVendor\MyApp\Batch');
$batch->shouldReceive('__call')->with('increment')->once();
```

(I'm not sure why this didn't work when I first tried it though)